# Getting coordinates to display properly when imported from excel into ArcMap?

Tags: coordinate-system, arcmap, attribute-table, coordinates, arcgis-10.5

- Both the base map and the table imported have been put to same coordinate system.
- Is only showing a single point at a wrong location for all points.

[image]

- When I click "identify" for the single point it shows all my points with correct lat and long but with different location than the lat and long entered from the table.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot showing the excel attribute table? How did you create the points?

Comment: Anyone know what the canonical Q&A / community wiki is for this? It's a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Don't assign the data frame's coordinate system to the event layer. Assign the correct GEOGRAPHIC coordinate system. Then ArcMap will be able to project the latitude/longitude points to the data frame's coordinate system.

ArcMap needs to know what coordinate reference system the coordinates are in, before it can project them to another coordinate reference system.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of your basemap.

Don't drag identify tool around the point tool. Just click on the exact position of the point.
Check the dataframe coordinate system, close the basemap, then use "Identify" tool.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove (delete) your layer and shape file that created in ArcMap based on your excel file. Remove your basemap.
2. On data frame properties choose the coordinate system for your points in your excel file.
3. Transfer your points to ArcMap and check the coordinate system for your shapefile. Make sure to choose the right coordinate system.
4. Define the projection for your shapefile if it is not defined or use project tool if it shows wrong coordinate system.

You might be able to skip step 2.